# Run external python file with arguments from Java code

Tags: java, python, shell, processbuilder

I have a python script in another folder from my Java files. I need to run it with arguments.

I was reading up on `ProcessBuilder` but can't figure out how to use it. The arguments will be supplied by Java variables. Basically, I want to do this with Java code:

`python /path/to/script.py -s java_var1_here -r java_var2_here -d` (This has five arguments being passed to the script. Three of them are flags)

I was reading this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html, but as I said it doesn't make much sense to me.

I only have this so far: `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python", "/path/to/script.py");` I tried adding the arguments right after script.py but was unsuccessful.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Try `Runtime.exec(cmd)`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html

Comment: With that, I would have to put my command in a string then pass the string to `exec()`?

Comment: Yeah, better: a String[]

Comment: Have you considered using Jython to run it from within the JVM?

Comment: Why an array? Will each index be a new argument? For example `[0] = "python", [1] = "/path/to/script.py", [2] = "-s", [3] = java_var, etc...`.

Comment: I have never heard of Jython. I'll look it up.

Comment: @CeeC I guess, leaving it to the implementation to handle each argument makes it more flexible for unknown numbers of arguments and more robust if your arguments contain spaces or other nasty stuff.

Comment: @CeeC Sth along the lines of: `runtime = Runtime.getRuntime(); p = runtime.exec(yourArray); p.waitFor();`

Comment: Is `runtime` a `Runtime` reference variable? And what is `p`? I was doing this: `String [] args = {"python", "/path/to/script.py", "-s", var, etc...}; Runtime.exec(args)`. However, that doesn't work because my method is not static.

Comment: You need a Runtime instance (there is only one such instance) which you get via `.getRuntime()`. `.exec()` returns a `Process` instance, and calling`.waitFor()` lets your current thread wait until the subprocess `p` has finished (in case your following code needs the results of said process afterwards)

Answer (score 0):

Sth along the lines of:
`runtime = Runtime.getRuntime(); p = runtime.exec(yourArray); p.waitFor();`
You need a Runtime instance (there is only one such instance) which you get via `.getRuntime()`. `.exec()` returns a `Process` instance, and calling`.waitFor()` lets your current thread wait until the subprocess `p` has finished (in case your following code needs the results of said process afterwards)
                    – schwobaseggl